# How do I get the url for a web site in an arm template for use in another resource?

Tags: azure-resource-manager

I have an arm template for a resource group with a website (`"type": "Microsoft.Web/sites"`) among other things.  I am adding a logic app to call a url on the website every 15 minutes.  Is it possible to pull the deployed url of the website?  We are not setting the url directly, but it is using `"name": "[parameters('SiteName')]"` I think to come up with `<SiteName>.azurewebsites.net`.  I thought it should be simple to pull the url into my logic app, but I don't see a way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As mentioned, use the "reference" function... here's the syntax:

```
[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', parameters('SiteName')), '2018-02-01').defaultHostName]
```

...where you are specifying the name of the App Service in a parameter, specifying the Schema of the template used to create the App Service, and using the "defaultHostName" property of the App Service.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah it should be possible. I believe the way that you mentioned should work, but you should be able to also pull the host name from the resource itself.

You can use ARM template "reference" function to do this and pass it as a parameter to your logic app:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-functions-resource#reference

It looks like under properties the Microsoft.Web/sites returns a default host name as well as a list of host names.